# Vim search confusion: /, ? and g/ mixed error

Tags: vim

When I use "/" or "?" to search in vim, it acts the same as "g/". Does someone know how to figure it out? I don't change any settings on them.

Figures below are the details.

### "/" condition

[image]

### "?" condition

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Your screenshots look perfectly normal, given the fact that you confuse `hlsearch` and `incsearch`.

Comment: Figures are not the details, whoever said "a picture is worth a thousand words" lied. We can't help you unless we can understand exactly what it is that you find to be a problem.

Comment: @romainl I want to say: in figure1, I search the word "set" using "/" at line 42, but the vim gives me all the global search results just like 'g/' effects. While I only need the ones after line 42. Meanwhile, in figure2 I use "?" to search "set" results only before line 40. However, vim gives me all the results before and after line 40. What's wrong with it? thanks.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for your help. I redescribed it at reply above. Can you figure it out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As @romainl said, you're confusing two different related things. Vim will *highlight* all matches, if your `hlsearch` is set. Vim will *move the cursor* to only one of the matches, forwards or backwards depending on the operator.

Comment: @romainl Like you said, vim will highlight all matches whenever the operator("/", "?", "g/") I use. But actually I only need the before or the after ones. If so, what's meaningful points of these global match highlights for users? By the way, Is there any possibility that if I use "/", vim only highlights the matched results after current line?

Answer (score 3):

What's worse than undocumented code? Badly documented code.

From your `vimrc`:

```
set hlsearch " highlight matches when typing...
```

Your comment doesn't describe the `hlsearch` option. It describes the `incsearch` option.

If you want the behavior described in the comment, `set incsearch`.

If you want to describe what `hlsearch` does, try the following:

```
set hlsearch " highlight all occurrences of the last search pattern
```

It seems like you don't want `hlsearch` so *why* did you enable it in the first place?